# while activating virtual environment in python showing this

Tags: python, django, executionpolicy

ps1 cannot be
loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

run this command  "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"

then showing this

To change the execution policy for the
default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with
the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution
policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope
CurrentUser"

Comment: which operating system.  please provide details to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 1):

So did you run PowerShell as admin?

I don't really understand if you are explaining what you did or the fix.

Try this:

- Run PowerShell as admin
- `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`